# How to close an Excel data connection after the data has been refreshed?

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection, connection-string

My concern is I have a `xcopy` file that will periodically overwrite the files my Excel file is connected to via a data connection. If my Excel file has open connections to my other data sources then I believe it will not overwrite the file and just save it under another file name [(e.g. From having a name of: Excel Data -> Excel Data (1)]

I am wondering if there is a way I can just pull the data out from those files, then immediately close the connection.

Normally the default for one parameter is `Mode=Share Deny Write` I changed it to `Mode=Share Deny None` but does not seem to work.

I also tried `ThisWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled = False` prior to running the refresh macro:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - JO")
     .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
     .Refresh
End With
```

Then I turn the connection on via: `ThisWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled = True`

But I get an error on `ThisWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled = False` saying: `Compile error: Can't assign to read-only property`. (Note: The same error appears for `ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled = False`)

My `Connection String` is shown below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Password="";
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=C:\Users\Test.MDB;
Mode=Share Deny None;
Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****;
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2l
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;
```

Comment: Have you tried `Mode=Read` instead?

Comment: @CLR Yes I have it only turns the data source file as read only when I open. But that means a person cannot edit it.

Comment: Ah okay. My understanding was that if opened as Read, it would be possible to overwrite the file regardless of the state of connection. My bad.